# System configuration tool for Windows

Tags: windows

What are the free tools/commands available for Windows XP/Vista/7 (in a single click) that will provide few basic system configuration like processor, RAM size, hard disk capacity, etc.?

I feel/believe this question is eligible to be posted in [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit `Win + R` and type `msinfo32`.

Comment: That command was useful. Because I don't have enough reputations (only 1 as of now), am not able to vote up. Sorry for that.

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PC Wizard](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/pc-wizard.html) from CPUID. For more information about your processor, you can use [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html)

Comment: That link was useful.  Because I don't have enough reputations (only 1 as of now), am not able to vote up.  Sorry for that.

Comment: Don't worry! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

right click My Computer > Properties to get the basic system configuration.
right click My Computer > Properties > Hardware >Device manager to get a little advanced configuration.
On windows 7 also offers widgets which display system info like processor activity and RAM usage etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another tool, which is just an EXE (no installation required), called [System Spec](http://www.alexnolan.net/software/sysspec.htm).

**Excerpts:**
System Spec - A Portable Freeware System Information Utility.
System Spec gives you a complete specification and system information of your PC. This includes hardware, software and settings.

With System Spec you can see, save and print a complete spec of your PC. This standalone, system information utility can also perform various windows functions. Additional advanced info includes CPU, drives, applications, display, memory, networking, internet, CD / DVD drives and more.